# Random generation of tuple (A, B) so that A + B <= C?

Tags: random

*After the discussion in the comments I must note that terms used here are out of math context, not programming context.*

How can I uniformly generate random tuples of natural numbers `A` and `B`, so that `A + B <= C`, where `C` is constant?

Each possible tuple that meets the criteria should have an equal chance of being generated. For the purposes of this question, a natural number means a positive integer greater than or equal to 1.

---

**Wrong solution** (just to explain the question): take random `A` from `1` to `C`, take random `B` from `A` to `C`. This way you're as likely to get a tuple where `A = 1` as the tuple where `A = C`, but you have `C` tuples of first kind and only 1 tuple of the second kind, so individual tuples of these types don't appear with the same probability.

Comment: I have a close flag about this being "debugging help". I would be very curious about how this could be even remotely considered that.

Comment: Are the tuples integral or fractional?

Comment: It's hard to determine what outcome you're actually looking for. What you're describing is *not* uniform.

Comment: @MarkRansom: it means that if `C=2` and `A` and `B` would be integral, you would randomly pick from `{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(0,2)}`I think...

Comment: @Mark, how did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: Which quantity or quantities exactly need to have a uniform distribution? The sum of A + B, or the individual values of A and B? Enforcing the constraint means the second isn't possible I think.

Comment: @CommuSoft `tuples of natural numbers` http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number

Comment: @CommuSoft your example shows 3 possibilities where A=0 but only 1 where A=2. Given the "wrong solution" that isn't the intended result.

Comment: @samgak the tuple needs to be uniform, not one of it's qualities. Each possible tuple that confirms to this condition should have the equal probability of being generated.

Comment: @MarkRansom: that's the point I'm making... The tuples should be drawn uniformly.

Comment: @MarkRansom the wrong solution would generate the same set of tuples, but not uniformly.

Comment: OK, I think I finally understand and @CommuSoft was right - you want *each possible conforming tuple* to have an equal chance of being selected?

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, this is what written in the question. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(discrete)

Comment: I must have specified in the beginning that I use these terms as they are used in probability theory, and not in programming.

Comment: @MaxYankov: two questions: *a* and *b* are positive? And are they reals or ints?

Comment: @CommuSoft en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number positive integral numbers starting with 1.

Comment: @MaxYankov the wikipedia article you link says there's no universal agreement as to whether 0 is or is not included.  You really should edit your question to remove the ambiguities, rather than trying to address them here in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a given natural number C, there are (C-1) * C / 2 possible natural number<sup>*</sup> tuples where A + B <= C

e.g. C = 5, the 10 possible natural number tuples are:

```
(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4)
(2,1), (2,2), (2,3)
(3,1), (3,2)
(4,1)
```

So you could choose a random value between [1, (C-1) * C / 2] and find the tuples based on that.

To make it easier to find the tuple, imagine the list doubled with the triangle flipped around and fitted to itself:

```
(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (1,4), (4,1)
(2,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,2), (3,1)
(3,1), (3,2), (2,3), (2,2), (2,1)
(4,1), (1,4), (1,3), (1,2), (1,1)
```

Now you just need one random number for the row in the range [1, C-1] and one for the column in the range [1, C]

If the row + column <= C then A = row, B = column

Otherwise A = C - row, B = C + 1 - column

(*) <sub>Going by the definition of a natural number as a "positive integral starting with 1" given by the OP, which is not the only possible definition of a natural number</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**Edited for updated question**

Generate two numbers:

- *X ~ U(1, C)*
- *Y ~ U(1, C - X)*

Now toss a coin:

- with probability 1/2, *A <- X, B <- Y*
- with probability 1/2, *A <- Y, B <- X*

Comment: The `=` in the first version of the question was there by mistake. Please read updated question.

Comment: That's not uniform: the Y will in general be smaller than X because the bound is lower.

Comment: @CommuSoft Hence the final toss about which is A and which is B.